# Issue with running React Native project on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm currently facing an issue while trying to run my React Native project on iOS. I have followed the necessary steps, but I keep encountering an error during the build process running
`npm run ios`

I have tried various troubleshooting steps, such as updating dependencies, cleaning the project, and verifying my environment setup. However, I haven't been able to resolve the issue so far.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance on how to resolve this problem. If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has any suggestions, please feel free to contribute to the discussion.

Thank you in advance for your help!

The log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/Users/ns12/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/ns12/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'ios'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.13
3 info using node@v14.17.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'preios', 'ios', 'postios' ]
5 info lifecycle geocamere-app@1.0.0~preios: geocamere-app@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle geocamere-app@1.0.0~ios: geocamere-app@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle geocamere-app@1.0.0~ios: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle geocamere-app@1.0.0~ios: PATH: /Users/ns12/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/ns12/Documents/geocamere-app/node_modules/.bin:/Users/ns12/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Users/ns12/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/bin
9 verbose lifecycle geocamere-app@1.0.0~ios: CWD: /Users/ns12/Documents/geocamere-app
10 silly lifecycle geocamere-app@1.0.0~ios: Args: [ '-c', 'expo run:ios' ]
11 silly lifecycle geocamere-app@1.0.0~ios: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle geocamere-app@1.0.0~ios: Failed to exec ios script
13 verbose stack Error: geocamere-app@1.0.0 ios: `expo run:ios`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/ns12/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:375:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/ns12/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:375:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid geocamere-app@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/ns12/Documents/geocamere-app
16 verbose Darwin 21.6.0
17 verbose argv "/Users/ns12/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/bin/node" "/Users/ns12/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/bin/npm" "run" "ios"
18 verbose node v14.17.3
19 verbose npm  v6.14.13
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error geocamere-app@1.0.0 ios: `expo run:ios`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the geocamere-app@1.0.0 ios script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

React Native Version
0.71.3